# Should I be using DeploymentItem attribute in CodedUI?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have few automated test cases written with CodedUI, and I'm using Excel file for keeping test data as my DataSource and also using XML files for keeping the Element locators (ID, Name etc.)

All these external files have value of 'Copy to Output Directory' set to 'Copy Always', because of this these files get copied to '..\bin\Release\' folder.

Let say I want to place my test cases on a different machine just for execution purpose, so I should be copying all the content of '..bin\Release\' folder to that machine?

Or Should I define DeploymentAttribute or make then part of .TestSettings file so that all files also get copied to Output Directory (inside Out folder) i.e. created at run time.

From where CodedUI should read these external files during execution when running over a different machine?